# converting a string to c reserved words

Tags: arrays, c, string, type-conversion, sizeof

I'm trying to print out the size of various data types I have in an array as strings, like so:

```
printf("%lu", sizeof(list_of_datatypes[i]))
```

A string for example would be "*char*", or "*unsigned int*".
Is there a way I could get sizeof to see them as the reserved words they are in c?

Comment: You can't do that.  The `sizeof` operator takes expressions or type names as an argument, and the result is evaluated at compile time (except for variably-modified types).  It does not treat a string such as `”char”` as a type name.

Comment: mortonPI, Why did you code `"%lu"` to match the return type of `sizeof(list_of_datatypes[i])`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I figured as much. Is there any way to explicitly convert it?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's what gcc appears to expect of sizeof. Printfing as anything else returns an error.

Comment: @mortonPI "Printfing as anything else returns an error" is doubtful.  Rather the use formats based on trial and error, use the specified matching one: since C99: `"%zu"`.  `"%lu"` may work for your compilation, but is not a portable solution.

Comment: If you look at the other things you do with those type-name-containing strings you will notice that you have switch-cases or if-constructs to do anything with them already. Extend those for the size information, by using the compilers  `sizeof()`.  Trying to use strings as input to sizeof indicates that we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah, duly noted.

Comment: @Yunnosch Well, it wasn't really a problem to be solved, but rather an exercise which I ended up completing through old fashioned manual typing.

Comment: mortonPI, So you want `"char"` to return `, `"short"` to return 2, `"float"` to return 4, `"double"` to return 8, etc?  Perhaps post your array of _strings_.  There are ways to efficiently tackle that problem.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Again, it was never so much a "problem" to begin with. More just general curiosity.

But keeping that in mind, lets say my array of strings is something like:
```char array[][] = {"char", "int", "double", "unsigned int"};```

Comment: @mortonPI Using a _select_ hash function on each of those strings, code can quickly come up with the size of various data types.  The trick, of course, is forming the correct hash function.  Good luck.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sounds like that would take more research than I can invest into it right now, but definitely something to look into in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. The `sizeof` operator takes expressions or type names as an argument, and the result is evaluated at compile time (except for variably-modified types). It does not treat a string such as `”char”` as a type name.

> Is there any way to explicitly convert it?

No.